# data type from Unix (.csv file)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `.csv` file which I want to bulk insert into my SQL server database, but I can't recognize type of data in one of column:

Example: `Fri May 10 09:35:28 EDT 2019`

I declared column as a varchar and it works, but it would be useful to type a correct type to manipulate with date/datetime later.

What I know:
`.csv` file comes from Unix or something like that.

I couldn't find solution and examples, so sorry if there was something similar.

I tried: `from_unixstamp`, I used `varchar` and next I parsed text (left, right) to get name of month and days.

Comment: Parsing is the way to go

Comment: Looks like the right data type would be `datetimeoffset`. You might want to put the data into a staging table, and use SQL  Server to convert the data into a `datetimeoffset`, as you'll be able to use functions to manipulate the value and provide style codes for `CONVERT`.

Comment: BULK INSERT will not be able to parse the string as desired. This could also be done in T-SQL using a varchar in a staging table and some ugly string parsing. I suggest you parse the value in an ETL app. For example, a PowerShell script with SqlBulkCopy could parse the value with `$dateTime = [DateTimeOffset]::ParseExact("Sep 08 07:36:58 EDT 2019", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss EDT yyyy", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)`. Note that the timezone will not be preserved if the target column is datetime/dattime2. You'll also need to convert it to local time in that case.